# Append XML into a new file using UTL_File

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, utl-file

I have an XML file created from DBMS_XMLGEN. Now, I need to put this XML file into a new OS like below. How can I achieve this?

```sql
v_file := utl_file.fopen (my_dir, filename, 'A');
    -- do something to put the XML file into this file
utl_file.fclose(v_file);
```

Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have `utl_file` or PL/SQL. Are you sure it isn't Oracle? Also, in Oracle `utl_file` is a package containing utilities for working with files, so I'm not sure what you mean by "a new UTL_FILE".

Comment: Hi @WilliamRobertson, thank you for your reply. Yes you are right, I meant to say Oracle SQL developer. What I tried to ask was that I had a CLOB call clob_of_xml, and I would like to add it into a new file. I solved it by UTL_FILE.fopen() a file name, then just utl_file.put_line(v_file, clob_of_xml). Thanks dude, I really appreciate that.